# Shell script loop over filenames from 0000 to 1500

Tags: shell

I'm trying to create a shell script that shall convert certain Files according to some rules. The files are organized like this:

```
file_0000.adat
file_0001.adat
file_0002.adat
file_0003.adat
...
file_0010.adat
file_0011.adat
...
file_9999.adat
```

My current script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

lauf=$(expr 0)

for filename in ../distData/file_*.adat
do
    ...
    lauf=$(expr $lauf + 1)
done;
```

But now I only want the files with numbers from 0000 to 1500. For the conversion I need the number of the file (done by the variable `lauf` in the script). Can't figure out how to do this right now.

Thanks for replys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for i in $(seq -w 1500) ; do
  if [ -f ../distData/file_${i}.adat ] ; then
    # do whatever, the file number is ${i}
  fi
done
```

Comment: Good one! Didn't know about `-w` in `seq`. I see in `man seq` that "equalize width by padding with leading zeroes".

Answer (score 2):

I tried something like this to generate the number pattern of the file.
You can put the other part of the code to concatenate with file name and search for the file name

```
START=0
MAX=1500
while [ $START -le $MAX ]
do 
    PAT=$(printf "%04d" $START)
    echo $START $PAT
    START=`expr $START + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FILES=$(ls ../distData/file_{0000..1500}.adat 2>/dev/null)
for FILE in ${FILES[@]}; do
    #$FILE exists, do what you want
done
```

the redirect of `stderr` to `/dev/null` is to suppress output messages for files in the range that do not exist

Comment: Far better to write `for file in ../distData/file_{0000..1500}.adat`, especially for patterns that may contain whitespace.

Comment: but then you have to do the `-f` check, so it's not the same.. What about setting the `IFS`?